# Java webapp - client certificate authentication URL

Tags: authentication, certificate, jetty

The [SecureRequestCustomizer](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/SecureRequestCustomizer.html) allows us to get the certificate(s) in the HTTP request. This setting is active for the whole jetty server (all URLs). So as soon as one requests any page from the server, the browser will ask what certificate to use.

Is it possible to have only a specific URL request the client certificate?

I would like to have a dedicated /webapp/login-cert URL that would trigger the browser popup to pick a certificate.